# Gaining SUDO privileges for 'child_process.exec'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `exec` from `child_process` in a node application to run some shell commands.

The problem is: I need to have `sudo` privileges to run some commands and I am not sure how to programmatically respond to the password prompt.

I do not want the application to hang until a password is entered by the user, I want the application to enter a default password and run the commands requiring `sudo` using said password.

Is this possible? Ideally, I would like to do this without first logging in as`su`, ie: just run the application and have it work.

Please no additional libraries.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Why not allow the owner of the process to run said commands without having to provide a password?

Comment: This is generally a very bad idea if you are taking any sort of user input. sudo exists for a very good reason... with disclaimer said:  it depends on what OS you are running, if you are running on Linux, you would put the commands you need to run as root in a sh file and use visudo to give that specific script root permissions. 

https://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/36-Always-Run-Script-As-Root.html

Comment: @Philippe I would like to do everything from within the node application.

Comment: @MatthewLerner as far as I know this is impossible for very good security reasons.

Comment: @FelixKling Basically, this is for an "in-house" app. I would like the user to simply run the app and have it "just work".

Comment: @FelixKling the only way I can think of to do it is to use a preconfigured docker container with the visudo already set up... but that wouldn't be in node, but would allow your package to be run with one command

Comment: or run node FROM the bash script, and use the bash to do the sudo stuff first before node runs. (user would still need to enter admin password to run the bash script)

Comment: @Philippe Interesting. I will definitely be running this in a "sandboxed" environment. I will try your docker suggestion if my search fails, I am just holding onto hope because I dimly recall reading an article where someone used `stdin.write`--possibly to respond to the password prompt, I just do not recall how it was used and cannot find that article anymore.

Comment: I think you might misunderstand what sudo dose, sudo breaks the sandbox and gives full root privileges... ie the ability to play outside the sandbox. unless you are using a virtual machine or docker, as they use artificial roots.

Comment: Just to be very clear of the danger of sudo here, sudo gives permission of your system root, including sensitive OS files. a command with sudo could very well wipe your entire hard-drive or install dangerous programs like viruses and Trojans. I've seen many a servers that have been turned into spambots sending thousands of emails an hour. sudo is dangerous, I can't stress this enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the SUID on the file so that it always runs with the permissions of the file owner or GUID if you want it to run with the permissions of the group. More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)